# Problems with converting Java code to delphi

Tags: java, delphi, delphi-xe4

I have a method that must return a generic interface. Have tried to make the method in delphi. But are unsure on how it should be written? Is there anyone who can help me?
Here's an example I've made in Java that works:

```
public < T  extends StandardDataProvider<?>> T GetDataProvider(String dataProviderName) {
    if (dataproviders == null)
        buildDataProviderMap();
    if (dataproviders.containsKey(dataProviderName)) {
        return (T) dataproviders.get(dataProviderName);
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Then tried to do the same in delphi .. But can not get it to work?

```
function TLocalDataProviderFactory. GetDataProvider(DataProviderName: string): IStandardDataProvider;  // Shows errors here? 
begin
  if not Assigned(DataProvider) then
    BuildDataProviderMap;
  if DataProvider.ContainsKey(DataProviderName) then
  begin
    Result := DataProvider.Items[DataProviderName];
  end
  else
  begin
    Result:= nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'T'

Comment: IStandardDataProvider is a base interface for other interfaces.
IStandardDataProvider <T> = Interface and the child is IEventDataProvider = interface (IStandardDataProvider <TUpdateTest>)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi generic constraints do not support wildcards. So the closest you can manage involves two generic parameters. The function would look like this:

```
function GetDataProvider<S; T: IStandardDataProvider<S>>(...): T;
```

Comment: Er, no, it compiles just fine.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas His previous Q was tagged XE4.

Comment: @Godfather75 Did you manage to fix whatever was wrong with your code and make this compile?

Comment: No I'm still having problems with the code .. I have tried your solution. But it just will not work? Can get it to work if I do not use generic .. but then I can only access IStandardDataProvider and not the others interfaces that inherit from it

Comment: What does "it does not work mean"? I made the code compile fine.