# How will this look like in Delphi?

Tags: java, delphi, delphi-xe4

My question is related to the one that I wrote in the last issue (["Problems with converting Java code to delphi"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774018/)) that I still have problems with. Java code seen in my last question is a part of my factory class that I am trying to convert to Delphi. The problem is that I have a main interface called `IStandardDataProvider` which contains common methods for the different classes in my factory. but since some of the classes also contains other methods that are not common to all of them. I use another interface that inherits from the interface `IStandardDataProvider`. The problem is that I can not get the generic to work? see my whole factory class in java. How will this look like in Delphi?

```
public class Factory {

    private static HashMap<String, IStandardDataProvider<?>> dataproviders = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends IStandardDataProvider<?>> T GetDataProvider(String dataProviderName) {
        if (dataproviders == null)
            buildDataProviderMap();
        if (dataproviders.containsKey(dataProviderName)) {
            return (T) dataproviders.get(dataProviderName);
        } else
            return null;
    }

    private void buildDataProviderMap() {
        // Build the database connection, that will be used in all the dataproviders
        DatabaseConnectionManager dbConnection = new DatabaseConnectionManager(ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration("sqlConnectionString"));

        // Instantiate the Hashmap 
        dataproviders = new HashMap<String, IStandardDataProvider<?>>();

        // Instantiate all the dataprovider implementations, and put them into the hash map
        dataproviders.put("EventDataProvider", new LocalEventDataProviderImpl(dbConnection));
        dataproviders.put("TaskActivityDataProvider", new LocalTaskActivityDataProviderImpl(dbConnection));
    }
}
```

**Update:** Okay here is my delphi version, which I try to make generic. Currently I have only access to `IStandardDataProvider`.

```
type
  TFactory = class(TObject)
  private
    DataProvider: TDictionary<string, IStandardDataProvider >;
    DbConnectionManager : TDatabaseConnectionManager;
    DBConnection : TSQLConnection;
    Configuration : TConfigurationManager;

    procedure BuildDataProviderMap;

  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function GetDataProvider(DataProviderName: string): IStandardDataProvider;
  end;

implementation

constructor TLocalDataProviderFactory.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  DbConnectionManager := TDatabaseConnectionManager.create;
end;

destructor TLocalDataProviderFactory.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  DbConnectionManager.Free;
  DataProvider.Free;
end;

function TLocalDataProviderFactory.GetDataProvider(DataProviderName: string): IStandardDataProvider;
begin
  if not Assigned(DataProvider) then
    BuildDataProviderMap;

  if DataProvider.ContainsKey(DataProviderName) then
  begin
    Result := DataProvider.Items[DataProviderName];
  end
  else
  begin
    Result:= nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TLocalDataProviderFactory.BuildDataProviderMap;
begin
  DataProvider := TDictionary<string, IStandardDataProvider>.Create;
  Configuration := TConfigurationManager.Create;
  DBConnection := DbConnectionManager.GetConnection(Configuration.GetConfiguration('sqlConnectionString'));
  DataProvider.Add('EventDataProvider',TLocalEventDataProviderImpl.create(DBConnection) );
  DataProvider.Add('TaskActivityDataProvider',TLocalTaskActivityDataProviderImpl.create(DBConnection) );
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you were told in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774018/), Delphi does not support wildcard generics like Java does.  The closest you can get is something like this:

```
type
  IStandardDataProvider<T> = interface(IInterface)
    ...
  end;

type
  TLocalDataProviderFactory = class
  private
    DataProvider: TDictionary<string, IInterface>;
    DbConnectionManager : TDatabaseConnectionManager;
    DBConnection : TSQLConnection;
    Configuration : TConfigurationManager;

    procedure BuildDataProviderMap;

  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function GetDataProvider<T>(DataProviderName: string): IStandardDataProvider<T>;
  end;

implementation

constructor TLocalDataProviderFactory.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  DbConnectionManager := TDatabaseConnectionManager.create;
end;

destructor TLocalDataProviderFactory.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  DbConnectionManager.Free;
  DataProvider.Free;
end;

function TLocalDataProviderFactory.GetDataProvider<T>(DataProviderName: string): IStandardDataProvider<T>;
begin
  if not Assigned(DataProvider) then
    BuildDataProviderMap;

  if DataProvider.ContainsKey(DataProviderName) then
    Result := DataProvider.Items[DataProviderName] as IStandardDataProvider<T>
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure TLocalDataProviderFactory.BuildDataProviderMap;
begin
  DataProvider := TDictionary<string, IInterface>.Create;
  Configuration := TConfigurationManager.Create;
  DBConnection := DbConnectionManager.GetConnection(Configuration.GetConfiguration('sqlConnectionString'));
  DataProvider.Add('EventDataProvider', TLocalEventDataProviderImpl.Create(DBConnection) as IInterface);
  DataProvider.Add('TaskActivityDataProvider', TLocalTaskActivityDataProviderImpl.Create(DBConnection) as IInterface);
end;

end.
```

Which really does not help you since you would need to know the concrete class that implements `IStandardDataProvider<T>` in order to even call `GetDataProvider()`, eg:

```
var
  Provider: IStandardDataProvider<TUpdateTest>;

Provider := Factory.GetDataProvider<TUpdateTest>('EventDataProvider');
```

Otherwise, forget trying to make the Factory itself support Generics, let the calling code handle it instead, eg:

```
type
  IStandardDataProvider<T> = interface(IInterface)
    ...
  end;

  IEventDataProvider = interface(IStandardDataProvider <TUpdateTest>)
    ...
  end;

type
  TLocalDataProviderFactory = class
  private
    DataProvider: TDictionary<string, IInterface>;
    DbConnectionManager : TDatabaseConnectionManager;
    DBConnection : TSQLConnection;
    Configuration : TConfigurationManager;

    procedure BuildDataProviderMap;

  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function GetDataProvider(DataProviderName: string): IInterface;
  end;

implementation

constructor TLocalDataProviderFactory.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  DbConnectionManager := TDatabaseConnectionManager.create;
end;

destructor TLocalDataProviderFactory.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  DbConnectionManager.Free;
  DataProvider.Free;
end;

function TLocalDataProviderFactory.GetDataProvider(DataProviderName: string): IInterface;
begin
  if not Assigned(DataProvider) then
    BuildDataProviderMap;

  if DataProvider.ContainsKey(DataProviderName) then
    Result := DataProvider.Items[DataProviderName]
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure TLocalDataProviderFactory.BuildDataProviderMap;
begin
  DataProvider := TDictionary<string, IInterface>.Create;
  Configuration := TConfigurationManager.Create;
  DBConnection := DbConnectionManager.GetConnection(Configuration.GetConfiguration('sqlConnectionString'));
  DataProvider.Add('EventDataProvider', TLocalEventDataProviderImpl.Create(DBConnection) as IInterface);
  DataProvider.Add('TaskActivityDataProvider', TLocalTaskActivityDataProviderImpl.Create(DBConnection) as IInterface);
end;

end.
```

```
var
  Provider: IEventDataProvider;

Provider := Factory.GetDataProvider('EventDataProvider') as IEventDataProvider;
```